# Java- Comparar numero con array y dar resultado

Tags: java, array

Buenas noches tengo que hacer un codigo para un ejercicio de programación,
en el que me plantea hacer un menu basado en un vector y en cada opción del menú realizar una operacion diferente.
Ya casi tengo mi programa terminado pero no logro terminar la opción(case 6), en la que tengo que comparar un numero introducido por el usuario y si esta en el array actual.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    int vector[]=new int [10];
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
    int num2 = lector.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Tu vector es:");
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        vector[i] = num2 + i;
        System.out.print(vector[i]+" ");
    }

    menu(vector,num2);

    lector.close();
}

public static void menu(int vector[],int num2) {

    int i = 0,opcion=0; 
    do {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("menu, etc..");

        System.out.println("Elige una opción");
        opcion =  lector.nextInt();

        switch (opcion){
        case 1:
            //demas case 2,3, etc.
        case 6:
            int num=0;

            System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
            num = lector.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Este es tu vector:");
            for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
                vector[i] = num2 + i;
                System.out.print(vector[i]+" ");
            }

            if (num==vector[i]) {
                System.out.println("\n"+num+" está en tu vector");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("\n"+num+" no se encuentra en tu vector");
            }
            break;  
            default:
                System.out.println("Gracias!");
                break;
        }
    }
    while(opcion!=7);
    System.out.println("Fin.");
}
}
```

Como podreis observar el problema lo tengo en el case 6.

Exception in thread "main" 13 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10

Alguien me podría ayudar? No se muy bien porque me da este error, o si estoy equivocada en el funcionamiento de lo que deseo hacer y lo que en verdad estoy haciendo.
Muchas gracias de antemano por la molestia de leer mi extenso codigo y ayudarme con mis dudas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Como podreis observar el problema lo tengo en el case 6.
> >
> > Este es el resultado por pantalla

```
Elige una opción
6
Introduce un numero
4
Este es tu vector:
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 Exception in thread "main" 13 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10
    at Act7.menu(Act7.java:124)
    at Act7.main(Act7.java:20)
```

**¿Por qué dio ese resultado?**

Analicemos este bloque de código para saber el porque:

```
System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
num = lector.nextInt();

System.out.println("Este es tu vector:");
for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) 
{
      vector[i] = num2 + i;
      System.out.print(vector[i]+" ");
}

if (num==vector[i])
{
     System.out.println("\n"+num+" está en tu vector");
}
else 
{
     System.out.println("\n"+num+" no se encuentra en tu vector");
}
```

El algoritmo de arriba lo que hace:

- Le pide al usuario un número, vamos suponer que el usuario ingresó un `4`.
- Luego, se ejecutará el bucle e imprimirá lo siguiente en pantalla: `4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13`. Ahora, la pregunta del millón: ¿Con que valor se quedó la variable `i`? Pues con el valor de 10. Cuando `i = 10`, el bucle `for` dejará de hacer iteraciones, esto se debe porque la condición `i < vector.length` dará un `false` como resultado y esto hace que el bucle termine.
- Luego se pasa a ejecutar esta sentencia:

```
if (num==vector[i])
```

Ahí está el error, como la variable `i` se quedó con el valor de `10`, estás tratando de [desbordar el búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), esto se debe porqué tu **VECTOR** solo acepta 10 **ÍNDICES**, de 0 a 9, si el `índice` es mayor a 9, se producirá la excepción: [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) (el error significa que el índice está fuera de límite, en tu caso, solo acepta índices de 0 a 9 y como `i = 10`, sobrepaso de `9`).

**¿Cual es la solución?**

Una posible solución, es declarar una variable de tipo `boolean` para que nos ayude a detectar si el elemento se encuentra en el vector o no. Esta variable si toma el valor de `false` significa que el número introducido por el usuario, no está en el vector, en cambio, si la variable tomara el valor de `true`, significará que el número ingresado si está en el vector.

Código propuesto **(solución)**:

```
boolean estaEn = false;

System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
num = lector.nextInt();

System.out.println("Este es tu vector:");
for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) 
{
      vector[i] = num2 + i;
      System.out.print(vector[i]+" ");
      if(num == vector[i]) 
          //Esta asignación quiere decir que el valor si se encuentra en el vector
          estaEn = true;
}
//Si estaEn es true, quiere decir, que el valor si se encuentra en el vector
if (estaEn == true)
{
     System.out.println("\n"+num+" está en tu vector");
}
else //De lo contrario, no se encontrará, esto pasará si la variable estaEn vale false.
{
     System.out.println("\n"+num+" no se encuentra en tu vector");
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte un tiempo en responder a mi pregunta, tu respuesta ha sido exactamente lo que necesitaba y ha sido muy clara y de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

pues veo que primero recorres el arreglo para mostralo.
Entonces por lo que veo tu comparacion

El vector solo compara la ultima posición, entonces tendrías que recorrer el arreglo de nuevo, inicializando el contadore desde 0. 
El error que te manda es que tu arreglo se desbordo.

> case 6:
>              int num=0,contadorB=0,contadorM=0;
>               System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
>               num = lector.nextInt();

```
        System.out.println("Este es tu vector:");
        for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            vector[i] = num2 + i;
            System.out.print(vector[i]+" ");
        }
        for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
           if (num==vector[i]) {
            vector[i] = num2 + i;

            contadorB++;
                }
                if(num!=vector[i]) {

                vector[i] = num2 + i;
                contadorM--;
                }   
        }

        if(contadorM<=0){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(num+" No se encontro");
        }if(contadorB>0){
            System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(num+" Si exite en el arreglo ");
            }
            contadorB=0;
            contadorM=0;
        break;
```